# How to call a visualforce page in modal popup jquery?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I created a visualforce page where i've a  tag. When it is clicked, i want to open another visualforce page in the modal popup query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could put an IFRAME in the DIV tag that renders the modal popup window, and then render your second Visualforce page inside that iframe?  That would probably be my first inclination.